# MongoDB locally to production

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I currently have an app running MongoDB, it works great locally. I am now struggling to find any information if I can host this on my server. Can I ssh into my server and install MongoDB or do I need a service like Mongo Labs?

Comment: You can do either. Your app just needs to be configured with the address to connect to.

Comment: Forgive me, but your question shows a lack of experience in administration skills that makes the use of a properly managed service imperative for production purposes.